# What's a convenient way to move files and subdirs "up a subdir" with possible name clash?

Tags: filenames, delete, move

I've some files and directories within the directory `/var/foo/bar/baz`. Now, I want to move all of them up into `/var/foo/bar`, and get rid of baz. Easy, right?

```
cd /var/foo/bar
mv baz/* .
rmdir baz
```

(I'm ignoring files beginning with . for the sake of this discussion)

but! What if `baz/` contains a non-directory file named `baz`? I can move it to someplace else, or use a temporary filename, then delete the directory `baz`, then move it into place. But that's tedious and a lot of commands, too... is there another, customary, simpler/more-elegant way to do thus?

Note:

- If there are other name clashes, the normal semantics of `mv`, which is to overwrite (and possibly prompt) are fine. But with `baz`, it won't do that, it'll just fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /var/foo/bar/baz
for src in *; do
    dest="${src}"
    suffix=0
    while [[ -e ../"${dest}" ]]; do
        dest="${src}.${suffix}"
        suffix=$((suffix+1))
    done
    mv -n "$src" ../"$dest"
done
cd ..
rmdir baz
```

A rather straightforward solution.  Prepare to move a file from the current directory to the parent directory, but if anything already exists with that name, add a suffix with a number.  But make sure not to use a number that *also* somehow already exists for some reason.

The construct `[[ -e file ]]` will return true if anything called `file` exists, whether it be a directory, socket, regular file, or whatever else might exist.

Comment: This isn't failsafe. Maybe I have files with lots of zeros? Unlikely, but possible... also, it's quite a hassle. 12 lines?

Comment: See my own answer...

Comment: I don't understand your complaint about "files with lots of zeros".  Nor do I understand what you mean by "not failsafe".  If you want to take care of all the nonconflicting files, just use `mv -n * ..` and deal with the remainder manually.  Anything more robust will require some logic to detect _and deal with_ any conflicting files in a way that will not itself conflict.  `mktemp` is not proof to never collide with an existing file (though it is unlikely); adding a numerical suffix will at least preserve the original filename for you.

Comment: If literally your only concern was "what if there is a file called `baz`", then yes, you can check for just that one case. But what about other files or directories that might be in the new files' location?

Comment: That was my literal concern, since you often get that when an archive is decompressed into a folder with the same name, but has the same name again as a folder on the inside. Anyway - with this code, I don't get `baz/baz` moved to `baz` eventually. And for everything else - I want an overwrite, just like with `mv`.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long, but should work:

```
cd /var/foo/bar
bazbaz_tmp_file=$(mktemp baz/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
[[ -e baz/baz ]] && mv baz/baz $bazbaz_tmp_file
mv baz/* .
rmdir baz
mv $(basename $bazbaz_tmp_file) baz
```

Note: This assumes that we can safely move any other files up from within `baz/`.